# Can I create a tree view similar to the outliner one with python?

Tags: python, interface, outliner, panel

That is the question:
Can I create a tree view similar to the outliner one with python?

The thing is that I want to structure some lists (arrays of objects) as tree-nested arrays, so they could be modified visually in a simple manner.

Can I create this kind of panel using Python?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to bse.  Have to ask the frequently asked, "what have you tried so far?".  Put together some code, and then,  if and when,  you come to a crossroad ask a question  regarding that.

Comment: I’ve searched over google and the documentation, I’ve asked in other forum (Blender artists.org) were I received a solution using BGL, but in that case I would have to create all the UI by myself, and since I’m starting out with Blender (not with programming) I don’t want to start with something too complicated like playing with OpenGL directly.

Comment: So the thing is if there is some kind of table view or tree view implemented in Blender’s UI that I can use it directly without having to play with Python, I have not seen anything similar in the docs, but I’m still not too familiar with the docs and if I’m honest, I still find quite hard to find what I’m looking for.
I can’t put any code together if I don’t know what part of the API should I use.
I hope this answers your question :)

Cheers and thanks for answering.